# Output colored, right aligned text into the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, python-click

I want to output colored text completly aligned to the right in the terminal (like in this screenshot of pacman ([packet manager of the arch linux distribution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman))(not colored)) [image: pacman text aligned to the right]

Currently I'm using `format`:

```
import shutil
left = "foo"
right = "bar"
width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
template = "{left:30}{right:{width}}".format(left=left, right=right, width=width-30)
click.echo(template)
# click.echo works just like print with some additional features
```

This works great until I add colors via ANSI escape codes:

```
left = click.style("foo", fg="red")
right = click.style("bar", fg="green")
# click.style just adds ANSI codes for colors and bold etc.
```

Which looks like this: [image]

I.e. the right side is not completly right aligned. Which is "right", because `right` is actually `\\x1b[32mbar\\x1b[0m` which of course has a higher lenght than `bar` and thus needs less spaces to be right aligned. Until the terminal gets the text and only displays `bar` (with color).

Am I missing anything in the python std lib or [click](http://click.pocoo.org/4/)? Or is there a simple library that deals with terminal colors and alignment that could help me? Or is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: AttributeError: 'shutil' object has no attribute 'get_terminal_size'

Comment: @xApple you are probably on python2, since version 3.3 shutil has the [`get_terminal_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size).

Comment: Well the question was tagged with just "python" and not "python3". The 2 series is still the default when unspecified IMO.

Answer (score 2):

[click](http://click.pocoo.org/4/)'s documentation does not mention alignment (which is why you are using python's built-in [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) class).  You could stay within the current set of interfaces by telling your script to remember the lengths of the strings before calling `click.style`, and adding the difference to the width used for the format call.  (This would not work as well if you were centering text).

There are perhaps other libraries, but you could use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) interface with the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter) function to draw single-line displays.

Comment: Sorry, i talked about the packet manager of the arch linux distribution, named [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman).

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to figure out that `click` provide a way to get the terminal size: `click.get_terminal_size`, the documentation is [here](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.get_terminal_size)

```
>>> import click
>>> click.get_terminal_size()
>>> (66, 24)  # (width, height)
```

And my solution, should works even you resize the terminal:

```
width = click.get_terminal_size()[0]
left = click.style("foo", fg="red")
right = click.style("bar", fg="green")
print "{0:}{1:>{2}}".format(left, right, width+6)
```

Since `right` actually is `\x1b[32mbar\x1b[0m`, we increase the width by hand to avoid the problem.

Edit: [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) is useful for me when do string format in python. It helps me understand string formating. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Is the "size" of the ascii color codes always 6? What is with bold text or multiple colors?

Comment: @syntonym It seems that with bg or fg or bold, `+6` still works.

Comment: bold **or** fg **or** bg works great. Unfortunately something like `right = click.style("bar", fg="red", bg="green", bold=True)` will not work (because in that case it should be +3*6. Somethinig like `right = click.style("foo", fg="red") + " " + click.style("bar", fg="green")` will also not work.

Comment: Ah, you're right, currently I have no idea for how to solve this :(

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'get_terminal_size'`